# Composing Multiple Futures and Option in Scala with ZIO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, zio

I just started evaluating ZIO to improve the programming model and the performance of my asynchronous Scala code. In my code base I deal with `Future[Option[T]]` often, and to this point I have dealt with that using Scalaz's `OptionT` monad transformer. Now I want to try this with ZIO.

Consider two functions:

`def foo: String => Future[Option[T]]`
and
`def bar: T => Future[U]`

I tried something like this:

```
val t = for {
       o: Option[Int] <- ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec =>
            foo("test")
       }
       i: Int <- ZIO.fromOption(o)
       s: String <- ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec =>
            bar(i)
       }
} yield s
```

According to my IDE, `t` is of type `ZIO[Any, Any, String]` in this scenario. I don't know what to do with that.

I want to consider three possibilities:

- The "success" case where `foo` produces a `Some` that can be composed with other functions on the value
- The case where `foo` produces a `None`
- The case where either function produces an error

I am not sure how to parse those possibilities in this scenario with ZIO. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple operators that can help you out in this case, basically instead of explicitly unwrapping the `Option` with `fromOption`, I would recommend using a combination of `some` and `asSomeError`

```
val t: Task[Option[String]] = (for {

  // This moves the `None` into the error channel
  i: Int <- ZIO.fromFuture(implicit ec => foo("test")).some

  // This wraps the error in a Some() so that the signature matches
  s: String <- ZIO.fromFuture(implicit ec => bar(i)).asSomeError

} yield s).optional // Unwraps the None back into the value channel
```

Comment: This is awesome. Elegant, idiomatic, and seemingly very much in line with the ZIO mental model that I am still working my way toward understanding. Thanks. 

And your RxJS book is awesome

Comment: On a related note, if I have a function `Task[Option[T]] => Task[U]` where I can produce a `U` whether a `T` is there or not, is there a ZIO API call to help facilitate that? Or is it simply mapping over the `Task` and then inside mapping (and `getOrElse`-ing) over the `Option`?

Comment: @Vidya Not that I know of, if you have a transform function I would probably just pass the task to it directly i.e. `transform(t)`.

Comment: For those who happen to come upon this question, just wanted to let you know that the documentation has expanded with the release of ZIO 1.x and [shows that this answer is indeed the correct one](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_creating_effects#option) despite the upvote counts.

Answer (score 3):

The type of [`ZIO.fromOption(o)`](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_creating_effects#option) is `IO[Unit, A]` which is `ZIO[Any, Unit, A]`, whilst the type of `ZIO.fromFuture` is `Task[A]` which is `ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]`, as documented by [Type Aliases](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_index#type-aliases). Thus the types do not align

```
ZIO[Any, Unit, A]
ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]
```

Try `mapError` to align the error types to `Throwable` like so

```
for {
  o <- ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec => foo("test") }
  i <- ZIO.fromOption(o).mapError(_ => new RuntimeException("boom"))
  s <- ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec => bar(i)}
} yield s
```

Comment: This looks like more of a hack to introduce an `Exception` (or more precisely, a `Throwable`) for the sole purpose of aligning the types to make the `for` comprehension work. While I appreciate the answer, it isn't really useful. This would imply that there is a more idiomatic way of handling this scenario outside of a `for` comprehension. Besides, how do you handle the `None` case? How do you handle the possibility of a "real" errors in `foo` or `bar`?

Comment: It's not a hack - if you want to compose computations, their type have to align. ZIO doesn't differ much in this regard from Either. What "magically" aligns in ZIO is the input/env. Other parameters will look for a common type to be upcasted to, which gives you Any of they are totally unrelated (like Option and Throwable in error param).

Comment: Yes, the purpose of introducing the `RuntimeException` is exactly as you describe. By "hack," I mean that the `RuntimeException` exists not to add business value but to make the programming model work. It doesn't matter what you do in `mapError` just as long as you call it. That doesn't feel awesome. But yes, you need to do that if you want to solve this with a `for` comp though there is still no answer to my question on parsing out the three scenarios

Comment: With the release of v1.x of ZIO, the documentation has improved and now [shows](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_creating_effects#option) that @paulpdaniels's solution for replicating `Option[T]]` is exactly right, which makes sense for the reasons we gave